# Illustrated short story about an AI being the last surviving being in the universe

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, webcomics

A few years ago I saw a colored comic? Graphic novel? (One big picture short story colored scrolled downwards) which talked about a short story involving a ship and an AI being trying to live. I totally forgot the gist of the story but the ending was that they lived throughout time until they were the last beings in the universe. It really gave me this existential crisis feeling.

Comment: "Night Watch"by James Inglis, the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66065/short-story-pre-1987-main-character-is-voyager-style-space-probe), is about an AI interstellar probe that eventually meets up with similar probes from other civilizations and, when the galaxy dies out the fleet of probes sets out for another galaxy. Could that be it?

Comment: The days of Solomon Gurksy? A man lives until the end of the universe.

Comment: Could this be Franck Herbert's "Destination Void" ? I read it a while ago, and can't remember if the end matches your description

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like Ryul's [webtoon adaptation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a8ud.jpg) of Isaac Asimov's short story *The Last Question*. It matches "one big picture short story colored scrolled downwards", and at the end of the story, the "AC" is the only being left in the universe.